# Junit 5 (jupiter) conditional executions with Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

I want to disable a test by default and want to @enableIf if a certain condition is passed. And I need to execute it with Maven.

I tried with these 2 options:

```
@EnabledIfEnvironmentVariable(named = "dbmigrationtest", matches = "true")MigrationClass(){}



@EnabledIf("'true' == systemEnvironment.get('dbmigrationtest')")MigrationClass (){}
```

I tried with these different commands

- mvn clean install -Ddbmigrationtest="true" -Dtest=MigrationTest
- mvn clean install -DargLine="-Ddbmigrationtest=true" -Dtest=MigrationTest

  But the result is always, one test run but 1 test was skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Those are JVM system properties you are referring to, not operating system environment variables.

Thus, you need to use `@EnabledIfSystemProperty` instead of `@EnabledIfEnvironmentVariable`.